# Does Maria DB support ANSI-89 join syntax

Tags: sql, database, join, syntax, mariadb

Does Maria DB support ansi-89 join syntax?

```
SELECT sites.site_id, sites.site_name, pages.page_id, pages.page_title
    FROM sites, pages
    WHERE sites.site_id = pages.site_id;
```

or only ansi-92 syntax?

```
SELECT sites.site_id, sites.site_name, pages.page_id, pages.page_title
FROM sites 
INNER JOIN pages
ON sites.site_id = pages.site_id;
```

Comment: It would be stupid if this was not supported, as both variations are still valid join-syntax in Standard SQL. But why don't you simply try it?

Comment: Please help me on this, i dont have maria DB. If any one have it. Please try out and reply.

Comment: If you don't have why do you care?

Comment: (Sorry, I don't know the answer to your question, but...)  Do not use the comma-JOIN format.  I suspect it allows the comma-JOIN in order to be compatible with MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - yes, both options are supported.